# NoClassDefFoundError could not initialize class

Tags: java

I have one class and it is getting `List` of values from database and I need to set those values to the `map`,

```
public class LocationField {
    @Resource
    protected static SearchDaoImpl searchDao;
    public static List<Object[]> list = searchDao.getResult();
    private static final Map<String,LocationField> TYPES = new  LinkedHashMap<String, LocationField>();
    static{
       new LocationField(list);
    }

    public LocationField() {
      //do nothing
    }

    public LocationField(List<Object[]> listObject) {
       for (Object[] listObject: list)
            new LocationField(listObject[0].toString,listObject[1].toString)
    }

    private String type;
    private String friendlyType;
    public LocationField(final String type, final String friendlyType) {
        this.friendlyType = friendlyType;
        setTypes(type);
    }

    private void setType(final String type) {
        this.type=type;
        if (!TYPES.containsKey(type))
            TYPES.put(type,this)
        }
    }
}
```

previously above code is working fine for `static` data and it is setting to `map` object ex:

```
LocationField field1 = new LocationField("ok", "okay");
LocationField field2 = new LocationField("hi", "hai");
```

But I need to get the values from `database` and need to set to the `map` object so, I changed something as shown in first piece of code, but the problem is I am getting an exception saying

`nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.LocationField`

It is not showing the `line` number to find out where actually exception is getting.
I am unable to figure it out what is the cause for this? as per my knowledge the above class is not available to `jvm` at runtime, but why? can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: There's a typo here: `public LocatoinField(){`. Should be `public LocationField() {`. Also, you have other typos there: `LoncationField`. Can you run a local test to instantiate the class, so that EVERY form of constructor is called? If so, then it is likely a classpath issue, post deployment.

Comment: @ManoDestra please ignore my typos, this code is running on `cloud` where I don't have permissions to copy past the code, there is no typos on original code.

Comment: It will likely be a runtime classpath issue then, if you're able to instantiate the class locally.

Comment: @subbu can you include more logs to see the context of the error?

Comment: @ambes problem is the above code is running on cloud where I don't have permissions to copy past the, but I'll try

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your variable is static and within consutructir you are trying to change the variable. It will attempt to reinitialize which is not possible .